# Mark some points on a vector's plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have vector, `Y`, which is a *3600*-by-*1* double. I want to mark certain points on `plot(Y)` with different colors or shapes or signs.

I have these points in another vector, `y`, which is *63*-by-*1*. This `y` vector contains the row numbers of the points of the `Y` vector that I would like to mark on the plot.

For example if `y(1)` is `17` then I would like to mark `Y(17)` on the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty basic, you just want to use `hold on` to get the second plot overlaid on the first. And then you want to use your `y` to index your `Y` to get the corresponding values (i.e. on the vertical axis). Note that in my example data I use variables `X` and `x` to simulate data like yours, you can just leave these out completely because you already have `Y` and `y`.

```
Y = rand(3600,1);
X = 1:numel(Y);

%//simulate your y
x = X(randperm(numel(X)));
y = sort(x(1:63));

plot(X,Y);    %// The same as plot(Y)

hold on

plot(y, Y(y), 'r*');   %//Note that since R2014b you no longer need to specify a different color when using hold on (i.e. the 'r*' can just be '*')
```

Incidentally, I think you might want to rather call your `y` variable something else (like `x` maybe) because it technically represents a different type of value from `Y` (i.e. a different axis)